# Centre input field in table cell when removing table head

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

The title should sum it up pretty well...

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/m8h3u/), when you press the "switch" text, the jQuery creates a duplicate header in place of the original. The only thing wrong (for now) is that the input field moves to the right.

How can I stop this?

jQuery code for reference (Stack Overflow doesn't like no code):

```
function duplicate(){
    var w = $('#old').find('tr:last').find('td').map(function(index){
        return $(this).outerWidth();
    }).get();
    var newth = $('#oldHead').find('th').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    for (var i = 0; i < newth.length; i++){
        if (i<1){
            $('<span>' + newth[i] + '</span>').appendTo('#new');
        } else {
            $('<span style="width:' + (w[i] - 20) + 'px">' + newth[i] + '</span>').appendTo('#new > #newfloat');
        }
    }
    $('#oldHead').find('tr').remove();
    $('#oldBody').find('tr:first').find('td').each(function(index){
        $(this).css({'width': w[index] + 'px'});
    });
}

$('#switch').click(function(){
    duplicate();
});
```

Comment: Why do you replace the whole header?

Comment: So I can scroll the body, whilst keeping the header in place. At least, that's the plan.

Comment: @verism why don't you get the width of the first td as well?  What you are doing is changing that width which is what's causing your problem

Comment: The first td - or column - is meant to always expand to fill the remaining space. I don't store its width because it can and will change after the event has been triggered.

Comment: @MikeSpy see your point, but I know that's not necessarily always the case. Certainly it's true in this instance, but I've seen cells that are far wider that any content in their respective column, in other tables.

Comment: @verism, I didn't expressed myself correctly, that's why I deleted my previous comment. I meant that columns width get affected from text length.

Comment: I added borders to the table so you can see what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/DSHZ3/  The input field is still centered.

Comment: @SteveWellens - thanks, but I'd figured that already. The real issue is explicitly setting the cells width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with a `min-width` property on the offending `td` tags - as well as removing the left and right padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/verism/s7VBu/

If anyone knows of any pitfalls this may invoke, I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: If you do not remove the old table and just add position:absolute; to the #new div, will that conflict with your plans?

Comment: @m.spyratos I haven't tried, but absolute positioning may work in some instances - however the nature of the design I'm using means it's not an option in this case.